# Cómo determinar si una variable es 'undefined' o 'null' en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined, null

Deseo determinar si una variable no está definida o si tiene el valor nulo.

En el siguiente ejemplo, quiero que se ejecute la clásula correspondiente a la condición verdadera, es decir se imprima en la consola el mensaje "EmpName no está definido", sin embargo, se ejecuta la cláusula en "de otro modo" (else) ya que se imprime "EmpName está definido"

```js
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if(EmpName == 'undefined'){
  console.log("EmpName no está definido");
} else {
  console.log("EmpName está definido");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="esd-names">
  <div id="name"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var miVariable; //miVariable está definida pero tiene valor nulo.
console.log(miVariable)
```

¿Cuál es la forma correcta?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647867

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

En lugar de `'undefined'` (cadena) usa `null` (objeto global).

## Explicación

`'undefined'` y `null` no son lo mismo ni son del mismo tipo. El primero se refiere a una cadena y el segundo es un objeto global (véase [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/null), artículo de Mozilla Developers Network).

NOTA: Véase la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49260/65) de [amandiel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18376/amenadiel) en la que aclara la diferencia entre `'undefined'` (cadena) y `undefined` (palabra reservada) o bien [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/undefined) (artículo de Mozilla Developers Network).

### Fragmento

En el siguiente ejemplo se ha reemplazado `'undefined'` por `null` y se han ajustado los mensajes a imprimir para cada caso.

```js
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if(EmpName == null){
  console.log("El valor de EmpName " + EmpName); //Nulo
} else {
  console.log("El valor de EmpName es " + EmpName); //Cualquier otro
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="esd-names">
  <div id="name"></div>
</div>
```

Otra forma mas general es reemplazar la comparación (`EmpName == 'undefined'`) por el nombre de la variable (`EmpName`)

```js
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if(EmpName){
  console.log("El valor de EmpName es " + EmpName); //Cualquier valor
} else {
  console.log("El valor de EmpName es " + EmpName); //No definido
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="esd-names">
  <div id="name"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pero comparar usando `==` con null es técnicamente un falso positivo, porque `undefined` y `null` se coercionan implícitamente a `false` para efectos de compararse

Comment: @amenadiel  No me queda claro a que se refiere tu comentario en particular porque mi respuesta hablo de la cadena `'undefined'` no del primitivo `undefined` e incluyo una nota en la que menciono tu respuesta en la que por cierto no mencionas lo indicado en el comentario

Comment: En el primer ejemplo pones `EmpName == null` pero en realidad `EmpName` no es === a `null`. La igualdad no estricta coerciona ambos tipos a false

Answer (score 9):

El valor `undefined` no es lo mismo que el string `'undefined'`. En tu ejemplo, yo haría:

```js
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if(typeof EmpName === 'undefined'){
  console.log("EmpName no está definido");
} else {
  console.log("EmpName está definido");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="esd-names">
  <div id="name"></div>
</div>
```

o bien

```js
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if(EmpName === undefined){
  console.log("EmpName no está definido");
} else {
  console.log("EmpName está definido");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="esd-names">
  <div id="name"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: dato importante: "if(variable === undefined)" no funciona en todas las versiones de javascript, por otro lado "if(typeof variable === 'undefined')" es excelente y se parece al "isset(variable)" de php.

Comment: No tengo problema en mejorar la respuesta si provees un enlace que respalde la afirmación.

Answer (score 4):

Puesto que en `javascript` no hay un equivalente a `isset` como en `php` debes tomar en cuenta lo siguiente:

Si el valor de la variable es `undefined` usar:

```
if(variable === undefined){
...
}
```

Si el valor de la variable es `null` usar:

```
if(variable === null){
...
}
```

Si el valor de la variable es vacio:

```
if(variable === ""){
...
}
```

También puedes usar:

```
if(variable.isEmpty()){
...
}
```

Si no sabes que tipo de valor tiene la variable puedes obtenerlo con un:

`console.log(variable)`

Comment: Perdón estas en lo cierto, ya modifique el código, por favor revisa la respuesta con las nuevas modificaciones. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentarlo así:

```
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if (EmpName == null || EmpName == undefined){
  console.log("EmpName es NULL o no está definido");
} else {
  console.log("EmpName está definido");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var EmpName = $("div#esd-names div#name").attr('class');
if(EmpName == null){
    console.log("EmpName no está definido");
} else {
    console.log("EmpName está definido");
}
```

Comment: agrega una explicación del código o del por qué esto resuelve el problema

Comment: el fragmento no indica si la variable está definida o no, solo pregunta si es igual a null. undefined y null no son lo mismo.

Answer (score -1):

```
var dato=$("#dato").val('');
  if(dato==''){
     alert("no esta definido");
  }else{
     alert("esta definido");
  }
```